# Best way to create multiple shifted columns on a pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, shift

I'm a python newbie - so please bear with me.

I am trying to create a set of shifted columns in a dataframe. For example I have a DataFrame df:

```
                    heading      speed
time                
2018-09-03 14:53:02   195.0   0.000000
2018-09-03 14:53:07   195.0   0.416667
2018-09-03 14:53:12   195.0   0.138889
2018-09-03 14:53:17   195.0   0.277778
2018-09-03 14:53:22   195.0   0.972222
2018-09-03 14:53:27   289.0   1.944444
```

I would like to end up with:

```
                    heading      speed   prev_heading   prev_speed
time                
2018-09-03 14:53:02   190.0   0.000000   NaN            NaN
2018-09-03 14:53:07   195.0   0.416667   190.0          0.000000
2018-09-03 14:53:12   195.0   0.138889   195.0          0.416667
2018-09-03 14:53:17   195.0   0.277778   195.0          0.138889
2018-09-03 14:53:22   195.0   0.972222   195.0          0.277778
2018-09-03 14:53:27   289.0   1.944444   195.0          0.972222
```

I know how to do this with a single column:

```
df['prev_heading'] = df['heading'].shift(1)
```

But is there a way to do this with multiple columns at once say something like:

```
df['prev_heading', 'prev_speed'] = df['heading', 'speed'].shift(1)
```

It seems inefficient if I have to run the shift command multiple times, as I would like to parse the dataframe on once if I can.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can use df[['heading', 'speed']].shift()

Comment: This is not a duplicate - I am wanting to keep my original columns and create new shifted ones - as is clear in the example I gave.

Comment: So you assign the result of shift to new columns, df[['prev_heading', 'prev_speed']] = df[['heading', 'speed']].shift()

Comment: This is what I orginally tried - however I got the error `KeyError: "['prev_speed'] not in index"`

Comment: To be clear code run was: `df[['prev_heading', 'prev_speed']] = df[['heading', 'prev_speed']].shift(1)`

Comment: That works for me. What about `pd.concat([df, df.shift().add_prefix('prev_')], 1)`

Comment: df[['prev_heading', 'prev_speed']] = df[['heading', 'speed']].shift() works for me on your example dataset. What is the error message?

Comment: `File "./testitworks.py", line 116, in <module>
    df[['prev_heading', 'prev_speed']] = df[['heading', 'prev_speed']].shift(1)
  File "/home/actian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2682, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "/home/actian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2726, in _getitem_array
    indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
  File "/home/actian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1327, in _convert_to_indexer
    .format(mask=objarr[mask]))`

Comment: Thank Alollz - this worked for me.